# Custom Service Notification Styling no longer works in Oreo

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

Before Oreo using a custom service notification with custom actions and styling does work. Now while updating to NotificationChannel's I'm getting a default notification saying 'Tap for more information or to stop the app'.

Yet I'm finding no information regarding this change or what is missing regarding custom notifications in a Service.

What has changed and how can I fix this so that I have a running background service with custom actions? That is with a CustomContentView and a CustomBigContentView.

The Service is a long running background service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android show a notification not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345884/android-show-a-notification-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I came looking for an answer to the same question, and I found that it has already been answered in this thread:
[Android show a notification not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345884/android-show-a-notification-not-working)

Simply put, you MUST set an icon using the "SetSmallIcon" method when building your notification. If you don't have an icon, your notification will not have your custom text, title, or view. See the accepted answer in the link for more info.

PS. Adding an icon solved the problem for me. I know it sounds unrelated, but that really is the solution.